# Is it wrong to refer with "error rate" when speaking of probability of errors?

Tags: error

People often refer to alpha and betha in statistics ( respectively the probability of making a type I and a type II error ) as "rates" or "error rates".

Is it right? I know that *rates* is usually referred to past, meanwhile a probability is referred to future events.

Can someone make this clear?

Comment: In frequentist statistics _propability_  is not a _plausibility_ of event, but it's relative frequency in infinity number of repetition.

Comment: The standard definitions of frequency and probability have nothing to do with time.

Comment: Yes error rate is commonly used for error probabilities. Bill Huber's comment is correct.